# O Visual Studio 2013 é compatível com SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

Conectei a tabela do SQL com o Visual Studio, mas na hora de mexer na tabela aparecia uma mensagem dizendo que o SQL Server não era compatível.

Se não for mesmo, terei que baixar outro Visual Studio ou banco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se está dizendo é porque existe alguma incompatibilidade, mas em maiores informações fica difícil ajudar.

Em tese é possível usar ambos juntos mas pode precisar fazer algumas coisas. Há uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24351825/221800) mostrando que é necessário instalar uma [atualização específica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). Provavelmente resolverá seu problema.

Se isto não resolver pode precisar de algo mais, mas tem desenvolvedores usando ambos. ou poste mais detalhes.

De qualquer forma considere atualizar o Visual Studio para o 2015. Ele tem muitas vantagens. Ou para oi mais novo, não faz mais sentido manter versão antiga com o [Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/community/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é gratuito e praticamente completo.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado!
Consegui resolver aqui, era só atualizar mesmo kkkkk... Obrigado novamente!

Comment: @MárcioCristian a melhor forma de dizer obrigado aqui é aceitando a resposta, como você fez, e votando na resposta, que espero, em breve, você poderá fazer. Veja o [tour]. Você poderá votar em qualquer post no site assim que ganhar mais 2 pontos.